# tailwindcss 50% width all div

Tags: responsive-design, width, tailwind-css

```
<div class="flex overflow-y-auto">
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-red-500 ">w-first</div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-blue-500">w-second</div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-green-500">w-third</div>
  <div class="w-1/2 bg-yellow-500">w-fourth</div>
</div>
```

I wants 2 div per row, i can use a div wrap to (first, second) div, then use w-1/2 that times it works fine.
but if i have unlimited div its not possible to wrap all div in same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a perfect scenario for the `grid` layout.

While `flex` is designed for one-dimensional layouts, for a two-dimensional layout like the one you have, `grid` would be a better fit.

Switch the `flex` utility with the `grid` utility. Then, specify the number of columns by using `grid-cols-2`. This utility will limit the number of elements of each row to 2.

You can read more about the `grid-cols-{n}` utility [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-template-columns).

---

```html
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 overflow-y-auto">
  <div class="bg-red-500">w-first</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500">w-second</div>
  <div class="bg-green-500">w-third</div>
  <div class="bg-yellow-500">w-fourth</div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind-Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/70gtPyk61z)

[image: image of the result]